# Server Error in '/' Application MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
 CalculatorController
        public class CalculatorController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Calculator
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index1(double a, double b, string op="+")
            {
                switch(op)
                {
                    case "+":
                        ViewBag.Ketqua = a + b;break;
                    case "-":
                        ViewBag.Ketqua = a + b;break;
                    case "*":
                        ViewBag.Ketqua = a + b;break;
                    case "/":
                        ViewBag.Ketqua = a + b;break;
                }
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Index1 View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index1";
}

<h2>Index1</h2>
<form name="formcalculator" action="/Calculator/Index1" method="post">
    <div>
        Nhập a: <input type="text" name="a" size="20" />
        <br />
        Nhập b: <input type="text" name="b" size="20" />
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="+" /> +
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="-" /> -
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="*" /> *
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="/" /> /
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculator" name="btnOK" />
        @ViewBag.Ketqua
    </div>
</form>
```

URL: http://localhost:1524/Calculator/Index1
but

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Calculator/Index1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

Answer (score 0):

```
        // GET: Calculator
        [HttpGet] //  <---- instead of POST
        public ActionResult Index1(double a, double b, string op="+")
        {
        //....
        }
```

Comment: I'm using [HttpGet]
Browser notice
Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'a' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index1(Double, Double, System.String)' in 'MVCDemo.Controllers.CalculatorController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Tks, using Get instead Post ^^

Comment: Please think about providing more information as to why this answer will help

Answer (score 0):

Check your default route, and if it points to `Index1` method, then it should be able to be accesible via `GET` requests, not `POST`